# Drinking another Kos between the First and second Kos

Tags: halacha, blessing, mishnah-berurah, four-cups-wine

In siman 473:3 the Shulachan Aruch writes that one can drink as many cups as one would like but between the first and second one shouldn't only if a great need arises.

The Mishna Brurah discusses whether if one does drink in between the first or second does he need to make a bracha and he notes an idea that since the wine is before him he would not need to make another bracha.

Why in Mishna Brura 472:21 he brings the opinion that one should not drink the first kos again if they did not lean ,why doesn't the Mishna Brurah use the idea of the wine is in front of you and ones daas is not disrupted and one can drink again without making a bracha?

Comment: Perhaps the idea is that the 1st cup of wine is a specific mitzvah, and the mitzvah itself has not been fulfilled if you did not lean?

Comment: So then one should drink the first kos again ,but that's not what the Mishna Brurah brings

Comment: There is a distinction between birchas nehenin and birchas mitzvah regarding hefsek. Since this is all one seudah, there is no hefsek for nehenin, but a birchas mitzvah must be OVER LA'ASIYASAN, so a hefsek in that regard would nullify the whole kiddush itself.